# Find out if the system is linear and time-invariant

Tags: linear-systems

> Consider a discrete-time system which in response to input sequence x[n] (n integer)
> outputs the sequence y[n] such that
> $y[n] = 0, n = −1, −2, −3,...$
> and $y[n]=2 (y[n − 1] + nx[n]), n = 0, 1, 2,...$. Find out if the system is linear and time-invariant.

How do I check if it is time-invariant?
I know how to check for linear systems ie to check for homogeneity and additivity but the expression for $y[n]$ contains a term of $y[n-1]$ and I'm not how to tackle that, please help.

Comment: Do you know how to check if the system $y[n] = nx[n]$ is time-invariant?

Comment: I don't know. @Jdip

Comment: Ok, a system is time-invariant if a delayed input applied to the system results in an output delayed by the same amount. So is $y[n-n_0] = nx[n-n_0]$ true?

Comment: No it isn't. There's a $-n_0x[n-n_0]$ term

Comment: That’s right!  So if that’s not time-invariant, what about your full system? Notice that simple system is part of your full system.

Comment: @Jdip Here do we have to check if $y[n-n_0]=2(y[n-n_0-1]-n*x[n-n_0])$?